# "apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, fsck, shared-library

Whenever I try to run commands like:

```
sudo apt-get install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error message instantly:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Same situation when I use apt instead of apt-get.

P.S: I don't know if this problem is related to another problem I am facing where **every file in my system becomes read-only and the only solution is to run** `fsck /dev/sda9`. This happens every now and then at any random time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read-only problem is usually indicative of hard drive errors and, if it keeps occurring, it sounds like your hard drive could be dying.

I'm guessing liblz2.so.1 fell victim to some hard drive errors.  You can download the package manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/liblz4-1/download (assuming you're running 16.04/Xenial) and extract `liblz4.so.1` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.  You can also install the .deb directly by doing `dpkg -i /path/to/downloaded/liblz4-1_0.0~r131-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb`